# How do I resolve the tree conflict when merging branch with trunk in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project in the 'trunk' folder. When I needed to create a branch, I copied the contents of the 'trunk' folder into a new 'branch' folder. As a result, the directory structure looks like this.

[image: Folder Structure]

Now I want to merge the contents of the branch and the trunk into the trunk folder. How can I achieve that?

I tried by selecting '**Merge two different trees**' from the Merge menu of tortoise SVN.

I entered the trunk URL in the FROM field and the branch URL in the TO field.

However, it gives the error '**Tree Conflict**' for every folder because the names of the folders in 'Trunk' and 'Branch1' are the same. I want the contents of these folders to merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I copied the contents

You should use create branche function (*branch/tag* in windows context menue when using tortoiseSVN), so the branch and trunk will know there relationship.
This is imported to avoid tree conflicts

> I tried by selecting 'Merge two different trees'.

Better use 'Reintegrate a branch' (best for your purpose) or 'Merge a range of revision'.

Comment: Yes, but I can't help it now. I have already made changes in the branch and cannot use the branch function now. Can I still use reintegrate branch?

Comment: Not the best starting position, but I would try it. Can you create a new branch and transfer your changes to it?

Comment: Yes, instead of merging all the changes manually to the trunk, the approach suggested by Micha will be less time consuming.

Comment: Thanks. I create a branch using Tortoise SVN, exported the contents of my branch there and then merged using "Reintegrate a Branch'.

Comment: @Micha - I have made changes in both trunk and branch. When I integrated the branch back in the trunk, some of the changes in trunk were lost. How can I keep changes in both while merging?

Comment: @mridula - Normaly booth changes will keep, when use branches created with svb-branch-functionality. Hard to tell what goes wrong - need more information.

Comment: I had to first merge the trunk into the branch using `Merge a range of revisions` and then from the branch back to the tree using `Reintegrate a branch`.

Comment: Your line of action sounds good to me. The concrete Code my be the reason, but its hard to tell. Maybe you can create a new question with a example of code an your steps (post link here).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your trunk and your branch in different directories and perform your merge with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

Then consider removing your branch and recreating it again properly.

Answer (score 0):

If `Branch1` is modified tree of `Trunk` and you want merge changes from branch to trunk, you have to:

- Read SVN book, where process of merge is clearly written
- Use this knowledge

  - Checkout thunk into clean, unmodified Working Copy
  - in this Working Copy select in TSVN context menu "Merge" - Merge Branch (1.7 version, from memory, I have now 1.8 TortoiseSVN)
  - Enter full or relative URL to branch
  - Merge (or perform test-merge before real merge)

[image]

Comment: What about automatic merge of SVN 1.8? http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-merge

Comment: @bahrep - best way, but I suppose OP still has 1.7